# What is the meaning of 'var_export($_REQUEST, true)' in PHP

Tags: php, html

Can anybody please tell me what this means in PHP?

```
var_export($_REQUEST, true)
```

Comment: The manual should  be the first port of call for this. http://php.net/var_export

Comment: thanks.. i am novice to php.. this is very much helped me...

Comment: http://php.net/FUNCTION_NAME_HERE is your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It converts `$_REQUEST` to a string, which would evaluate to the array, then returns it.

See [the documentation of `var_export`](http://php.net/var_export).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your code tries to execute `var_export(Array, true)` in a shell as you have backticks around it (even though you most likely just accidentally put them when posting the line as code here on SO).

But without the backticks, your code exports `$_REQUEST` to PHP code which could be used to re-create an array with the same data.

Edit: Aww, now they have been edited away.

Comment: I think the backticks are double escaping of code in Markdown. Edit: Actually, they weren't there in the original post, so I've removed them.

Comment: Yeah, they obviously are - but some fun is always good. Actually I wanted to mention that fact in my answer but then somehow forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var_export($_REQUEST['true'])
```

Returns true to the client, if the operation was successful.

Otherwise you can send any message.